# How do I update several divs with SignalR?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, signalr

I used to have this table with different identifyable rows that were updated using SignalR like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Enable logging
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;

    // Proxy created on the fly
    var messageHub = $.connection.messageHub;
    messageHub.client.timeEnabled = true;

    // ... Removed main part of the body ...

$.connection.hub.start(function () {
        var table = document.getElementById("monitorList");
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            var item = document.getElementById("conveyanceId-" + i).innerHTML;
            messageHub.server.joinGroup(item);
        }
})
```

Now, the structure has changed, and instead of using tables, I'm using divs, where each container has a unique id: `container-@unit.UnitId`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.UnitDetails.Count; i++)
            {
                var unit = Model.UnitDetails[i];
                <div class="panel panel-inverse sl-unit-overview" id="container-@unit.UnitId">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <!-- Heading content -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <!-- Body content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question, I guess it's more like two questions:
1. How can I change my javascript to find each container like I did with the table?
2. Is my current way of doing it the correct way of doing it? (Feeling kind of uncertain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it :)

```
$.connection.hub.start(function () {
        $("#unitList > div[id]").each(function() {
            var unitId = this.id;
            messageHub.server.joinGroup(unitId);
        });
}).done(function () { console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id); })
    .fail(function () { console.log('Could not Connect'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementsByClassName`, which returns an array with all the items in the dom with that class, then you can iterate over that class. Of course you will need to add a class to the div you want selected (`class: "name"`).

See an example here: [How to get current element in getElementsByClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075819/how-to-get-current-element-in-getelementsbyclassname)

As for 2, I think you are doing fine, but would recommend using JQuery if at all possible (some native js does not work across all browsers). See: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/