# Remove [0] from getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to remove the `[0]` from the below and instead replace with iteration as appears to be the solution on another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075819/how-to-get-current-element-in-getelementsbyclassname)

However my knowledge is very limited so it may be that this is not the solution or a variation is needed. 
The function is being called on on-click and I'm only looking for the element that is clicked to be activated. 
For example if there are two occurrences of "thishere", only the occurrence which is clicked will be called.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function zxcv(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
    el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("thishere")[0].style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Seems you need to read about loops and iteration - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: **1.** Are there multiple elements having the same class? **2.** If yes, You want to remove class from all those elements or the first element only?

Comment: There are multiple elements with the same class name. I don't want all to be "opened" at the same time, just whatever one happens to be clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a loop.

```
function zxcv(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
    var elements = el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("thishere");
    for(var i in elements) {
           elements[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    return false;
}
```

### EDIT

As we talk in comments, to activate only onclick you can make this:

```
    function zxcv(el) {
      // catch element and set display block
        el.style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }


    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("thishere");
    for(var i in elements) {
      // we hide all elements
      elements[i].style.display = "none";
      // we handled the click event
      elements[i].click(function(e) {
        // we call zxcv with the element as parameter
        zxcv(this);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've copied the original snippet and I forget to remove the comment tags. Thank you for the remember :)

Comment: Thank you. This will likely be down to my lack of information but I was not intending for all the occurance os classname "thishere" to be activated at the same time, just whichever one was clicked. This solutions activates them all at the same time.

Comment: In your question, you are not asking for that. You need to edit your question and ask a good question. Explain what you need and what you have got. We haven't got crystal balls.

Comment: You are correct my apologies; my lack of understanding precluded me from including more information from the off. I thought just iteration was what was needed but evidently not.

Comment: Ok,I will try to understand what you need and will try to help you as better as I can. In theory, that you need is very very simple.

Comment: Thank you - I hope it proves to me very very simple!

Comment: Are you copy&paste or are you adapting to your real code? This works, but it need to be adapted to your code.

Comment: Adapted how? I replaced  'zxcv' and 'thishere' for all occurrences with the name in the code. Something else needs adapting?

Comment: Yes! Are you writing it inside a document.ready or something similiar? What is your html? Maybe it's better if you share a working fiddle / snippet. Read this and back with it: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: It should be working. My original code works, your first code posted also works but neither in the way I require.Your latest code nothing happens on click.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to apply the same style to *all* matching elements?

If so:

```
function zxcv(el) {
  el.style.display = "none";

  var els = el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("thishere");

  for ( var i = 0; i < els.length; ++i )
    els[i].style.display = 'block';

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This will likely be down to my lack of information but I was not intending for all the occurance os classname "thishere" to be activated at the same time, just whichever one was clicked. This solutions activates them all at the same time.

Comment: You didn't show how the function was being called; nothing in the question indicates that this is happening on-click, or which element was clicked. Please edit the question to include that information.

Comment: You're correct Paul. I have edited such my question so I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set up a loop similar to the Q&A you posted.

Steps:

1. Get an array with all of the elements whose class name is `thishere`

   `var elements = el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('thishere');`
2. Create a loop to iterate through each element inside the elements array

   `for(var i in elements) {
          elements[i].style.display = 'block';
    }`

For the above loop, `var i` initializes a variable that will be used to iterate over the `elements` array. Then you use `i` as the index for the element in the array `elements`

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the elements and apply style to [0]th element.

```
function zxcv(el) {
el.style.display = "none";
var elements = el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("thishere");
for( var i = 0; i < els.length; ++i ) {
       if(i===0)
       {
            elements[i].style.display = 'block';
            break;
       }
}
return false;}
```

Answer (score -2):

One of the ways:

```
function zxcv(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";        
    el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("thishere").forEach(function(i, elem){
        elem.style.display = 'block';
    });
    return false;
}
```

There are several ways you can iterate through an array:

- [forEach function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
- [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: `each()` is from jQuery, but this code is not jQuery, it's pure javascript

Comment: I meant forEach, which is ECMAScript 5. Sorry.